# Changing my contract date without telling me

Tags: contracts

I was working for an agency as a cleaner, and the company has now taken me on.  My contract start date was 28th August which is a bank holiday.  Our holidays cover for this.

When I checked with HR that I would be covered, they told me that my line manager confirmed my start date as the 29th August.  This was not confirmed with me.   I will now be out of pocket, as I would have been working if it was a normal day.  It feels like they are conning me out of pay or a holiday.

My question is, **Can they just changed the date to suit them, as my contract clearly states the 28th.**

Comment: I don't know how it works everywhere, but when I started in the middle of a month, my pay was determined based on (number of days worked) / (number of working days that month). Starting the 28 or the 29 wouldn't have any impact.

Comment: As you'll notice Jane edited your post. DO NOT SHOUT WHEN YOU WRITE A QUESTION

Comment: @gvo the question seems to be that the very first day of work which seems to be a paid public holiday, and that someone has amended a presumably signed contract, to the advantage of one party and the disadvantage of the other party.

Comment: OP, I think you should keep your bridges un-burned with the agency.  This may be a first-taste of what this employer is like.

Comment: If you have a *contract* then you have a *contract*. A contract cannot be changed by one side alone. If the other side does not honor your contract, you can get a lawyer and drag them to court. That's the only *point* of a contract. If hiring a lawyer is worth it, is a decision only you can make.

Comment: This question is actually unclear, because 28 August 2016 was not a bank holiday, and 29 August 2016 was. Does the OP work Sundays?

Comment: @Criggie As I mentionned, where I am, the way to compute the salary for a partial month would not be changed by that consideration.

Answer (score 4):

Are you supposed to work on Sunday ?

Because 28 August is on Sunday. This just seems like to be an honnest mistake.

Usually new employees start on the beginning of a new week (Monday) or a month (easier for HR and paid stuff)

Comment: I'd debate that employees usually start on Mondays. In my experience and profession, I find most people tend to start on a Wednesday. The benefits being that you have a few days to become accustomed, and you get some chill time between that and the next week so you're not being overloaded with information. I've done this at all 3 of my "big jobs" so far, and it's worked out pretty well.

Comment: 29th August was a national holiday in the UK, so it's highly likely that this is a simple administrative error that's been corrected.  I guess the question is, did you actually start working on the Sunday or the Monday?

Comment: @XtrmJosh Here in the UK (which I assume is the case also with the OP), people start jobs either on a Monday or the first working day of the month.  Or the first working day of a week if it's not a full week job.  I've never heard of people starting work on Wednesdays over here in the UK.

Comment: @Pete I'm also in the UK. Maybe it's specific to the companies I've worked at or even some sort of influence I've had on the recruitment processes...